# How to get btn-grp-vertical to include a dropdown option in radio input

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to provide a block of multiple choice buttons to the user: five choices, plus an "other" dropdown with a list of 30+ more options. I want to return the value of the selection for the same form element. Currently, the buttons display correctly but selecting from the dropdown is not mutually exclusive to selecting from the first five choices.

```
<input type="radio" id="Image1_${Cat1}" name="Image1_Category" value="${Cat1}">
                        ${Cat1}
                </label>
                 <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" id="Image1_${Cat2}" name="Image1_Category" value="${Cat2}">
                        ${Cat2}
                </label>
                 <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" id="Image1_${Cat3}" name="Image1_Category" value="${Cat3}">
                        ${Cat3}
                </label>
                 <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" id="Image1_${Cat4}" name="Image1_Category" value="${Cat4}">
                        ${Cat4}
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" id="Image1_${Cat5}" name="Image1_Category" value="${Cat5}">
                        ${Cat5}
                </label>
                    <select class="btn btn-secondary form-control"><label>Other</label>
                        <option>Other</option>
                        <option>Option1</option>
                        <option>Option2</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hmm..maybe not the best UI for that...maybe something like an "other" radio button that enables the drop downlist.

Comment: Is there no way to use the buttons? I have a radio menu and dropdown function currently working, but for UI reasons would strongly prefer to get the buttons working.